# Play audio(mp3 file) streaming with RTSP media server with Titanium AudioPlayer

Tags: android, audio, titanium, rtsp

I am a newbie to Titanium, and need to develop an simple APP that can play streaming music on Android 4+. I took the sample code of Titanium AudioPlayer and change it's url, but it does not work. [Titanium AudioPlayer sample](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer)

Does anyone has experience doing similar work for Android? I greatly appreciate it!

PS, I setup live555 media player to support RTSP audio streaming from some mp3 file. I try with desktop TLC player for this url, music plays properly.(url looks like this: `rtsp://10.0.2.2:8554/lovetheway.mp3` if from emulator, for desktop TLC I just use `localhost:8854`)

Comment: no body? I thought Android 4.0+ support rtsp audio streaming so must Titanium mobile. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From [Wowza documentation](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?62):

> Android devices can't play MP3 streams over RTSP/RTP in any combination (audio/video or audio only).